# JSON object parsing PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm confused how to parse a JSON object in PHP.

I have this object from Google API (I've removed my address details!):

```
stdClass Object (
    [routes] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [bounds] => stdClass Object (
                [northeast] => stdClass Object (
                   [lat] => 0.000000
                   [lng] => 0.000000
                )
                [southwest] => stdClass Object (
                    [lat] => 0.000000
                    [lng] => 0.00000
                )
            )
            [copyrights] => Map data ©2013 Google
            [legs] => Array (
                [0] => stdClass Object (
                    [distance] => stdClass Object (
                    [text] => 1 ft
                    [value] => 0
                )
                [duration] => stdClass Object (
                    [text] => 1 min
                    [value] => 0
                )
                [end_address] => xxxx
                [end_location] => stdClass Object (
                [lat] => 0.0000
                [lng] => 0.0000
            )
            [start_address] => xx
            [start_location] => stdClass Object (
                [lat] => 0.0000
                [lng] => 0.0000
            )
        [steps] => Array (
            [0] => stdClass Object (
                [distance] => stdClass Object (
                    [text] => 1 ft
                    [value] => 0
                )
            [duration] => stdClass Object (
            [text] => 1 min
            [value] => 0
        )
        [end_location] => stdClass Object (
            [lat] => 0.0000
            [lng] => 0.0000
        )
        [html_instructions] => xxx
        [polyline] => stdClass Object (
            [points] => wcrnIpdvH
        )
        [start_location] => stdClass Object (
            [lat] => 1.234567
            [lng] => 1.234567
        )
        [travel_mode] => DRIVING
        )
        )
        [via_waypoint] => Array (
        )
        )
    )
    [overview_polyline] => stdClass Object (
        [points] => wcrnIpdvH
    )
    [summary] => xx
        [warnings] => Array (
        )
        [waypoint_order] => Array (
        )
        )
    )
    [status] => OK
)
```

I want to get the last latitude and longitude which I've left as `[lat] => 1.234567 [lng] => 1.234567`

I've worked out how to get the distance by doing this:

```
$directions = json_decode($return);
$distance = $directions->routes[0]->legs[0]->distance->text;
```

However, getting the longitude and latitude has stumped me.

If you could explain JSONs a little thanks more so!

Comment: Paste your JSON into http://array.include-once.org/ for examples.

Comment: make it into an array by simply adding true as the second arg. for example: `json_decode($MY_JSON_STRING, true);`

Comment: That is a great website!  Helped me understand JSONObjects and how they work.  For anyone in the future to get the end co-ordinates use $array->routes[0]->legs[0]->end_location->lat;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
//northeast
$lat = $directions->routes[0]->bounds->northeast->lat;
$lng = $directions->routes[0]->bounds->northeast->lng;
```

and

```
////southwest
$lat = $directions->routes[0]->bounds->southwest->lat;
$lng = $directions->routes[0]->bounds->southwest->lng;
```